# How to select random tableview cell in XCode UI Automation using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3, xcode-ui-testing

I am performing automation using XCode UI Tests. In a scenario I have to perform automation on UITableView with multiple sections, is there any way I can get the count of cells from particular section and tap on a random cell from that particular group.

My UITableView is similar to below 
http://blog.apoorvmote.com/uitableview-with-multiple-sections-ios-swift/

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends on how you are getting your section and row information.  The way I would do it is using a dict with keys to hold the sections. So your sections titles being the keys in your dict, with your rows as values for those keys:

```
myDict.keys.count
```

To get the number of sections you have.  You could then use a func like this to get your random number:

```
func randomInt(min: Int, max:Int) -> Int {
    return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
}
```

So to give some quick puedo-code:

```
let sectionCount = myDict.keys.count - 1
let keyArray = myDict.keys
let randomSection = randomInt(min: 0, max: sectionCount)
let rowCount = myDict[keyArray[randomSection]].count - 1
let randomRow = randomInt(min: 0, max: rowCount)
```